# Pass-through bank account, that transfers everything to your wallet

Tags: banks, automation, money-transfer

Now you can buy everything worldwide with https://all4btc.com/ (former https://bitspend.net/ )

It would be nice to get money now also only in bitcoins.

I would like to configure a bank account in the way that if there are **incomings** on it, it **automatically buys bitcoins** somewhere for it to the current exchange-rate and **transfers them to my wallet**.

- Is there an online-banking software, where I could configure those kind of macro?
- which bitcoin-software can be completely automated to buy on certain events?
- in which country would it be possible to open this kind of automatizeable bank account?

Answer (score 3):

Bitcoin-Central is to-date the only exchange to describe the capability of an [exchange account being integrated with a bank account](http://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=129461.msg1382551#msg1382551).

It will be a EUR account.  There is no estimate on when this will be available.

Coinbase will draw funds from a bank account however they have not been able to keep up with the demand so there is no assurance that when funds are available in the bank account that a Coinbase order to draw those funds can be placed.

Dwolla is another method of drawing funds from a bank account for delivery to an exchange.  There is a several day delay between when the transfer request is placed and when the funds are made available in Dwolla for transfer to the exchange.